# Splitting Lines and Lines

Tags: python, file, list

so, I was wondering how I could split the lines of a file and put them into a list? I tested out a code that works for one segment of the list but not the other chunks:

The file looks like:

```
Rank Ballots

Riding 0

NDP LIBERAL GREEN CPC

NDP GREEN LIBERAL CPC

CPC LIBERAL GREEN NDP

NDP GREEN LIBERAL CPC


Riding 1

NDP LIBERAL GREEN CPC

LIBERAL GREEN NDP CPC

NDP GREEN LIBERAL CPC

LIBERAL GREEN NDP CPC

NDP GREEN LIBERAL CPC
```

and so forth.

This is the code for the first half, riding 0:
    line = f.readline()

```
 while line !='':
    district = str.split(line)
    line = f.readline()
    a.append(district)
print(a)
```

And this is the code I did for the second half:

```
header = f.readline().rstrip() 
riding = f.readline().rstrip()
riding = f.readline().rstrip()
votes = []

while riding !='':
    rank = str.split(riding)
    votes = []
    while rank != '':
        votes.append(rank)
        rank = str.split(riding)
        riding = f.readline().rstrip()

    print(votes)
    riding = f.readline().rstrip()
```

When I print it's just a blank space. I was wondering if anyone could help out. The output should look be a lists of lists for each riding. So, for Riding 0: it'd be [[line 1], [line 2] etc] and Riding 1: [[line 1], [line 2]] etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it for you -

```
import re

f = open('x.txt')
d = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines() if l.strip()]

groups   = {}
curr_key = ''
for line in d:
    if re.search('Riding [0-9]+', line):
        curr_key = line
        groups[curr_key] = []
    elif curr_key:
        groups[curr_key].append([line])

print groups

>>> {'Riding 1': [['NDP LIBERAL GREEN CPC'], ['LIBERAL GREEN NDP CPC'], ['NDP GREEN LIBERAL CPC'], ['LIBERAL GREEN NDP CPC'], ['NDP GREEN LIBERAL CPC']], 'Riding 0': [['NDP LIBERAL GREEN CPC'], ['NDP GREEN LIBERAL CPC'], ['CPC LIBERAL GREEN NDP'], ['NDP GREEN LIBERAL CPC']]}
```

Comment: The output should be a lists of lists for each riding but the riding shouldn't be in the list. So, for Riding 0: it'd be [[line 1], [line 2] etc] and Riding 1: [[line 1], [line 2]] etc.

Comment: Lol, I don't mean to be a pest. But, I'm not allowed to use a for loop to read the file and your method is unfamiliar to me .. I'm in an intro csc class. Is there any way for me to work with my original function?

Comment: whats the difference? while-loop, for-loop. either one. this does not matter, what matters is this logic fine? are you getting the correct output?

Answer (score 0):

So that is my code for you. hope it work

```
FileStream f = new Filestream(path,FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sf = new StreamReader(f);
```

Here

```
while !sf.EndOfStream:
    district = str.split(' ')
    line = f.readline()
    a.append(district)
print(a)
```

you fail at `str.split(' ')`;

Comment: that function works .. I already defined the line .. it only works for the first chunk.

Comment: That doesn't look much like Python.

Comment: As @DSM mentioned, that does not look like Python. In fact, it appears to be a cross between Java and Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = [L.strip() for L in f if L.strip()][1:]

data = []
group = []

for L in lines:
    if L.startswith('Riding'):
        if group:
            data.append(group)
        group = []
        continue
    group.append(L.split())

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[[['NDP', 'LIBERAL', 'GREEN', 'CPC'], ['NDP', 'GREEN', 'LIBERAL', 'CPC'], ['CPC', 'LIBERAL', 'GREEN', 'NDP'], ['NDP', 'GREEN', 'LIBERAL', 'CPC']]]
```

Comment: I'm actually not allowed to use the read method. Is there a way to modify the second function so it'll do what the first one does but for all the chunks of info?

Comment: This should do what you want. It skips the first "trash" line.